# SphinxQL - offset out of bounds

Tags: sphinx

I have a strange issue. I want to have an offset in my query, unfortunately it throws an `offset out of bounds (offset=2000, max_matches=1000)` exception when I go above 1000. I used `LIMIT 2000, 10` in this example.

I added `max_matches = 100000` to the `searchd` section of the config file and restarted the service, unfortunately, that does not fix the issue. I am not sure why that is.

Version: Sphinx 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Sphinx 3.1.1 with max_matches added in the config you should see

`key 'max_matches' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.`

In Sphinx 3 you're supposed to use "option max_matches=N" instead. For example:

```
select * from idx limit 2000, 10 option max_matches=100000
```

Comment: I used it on windows, there was no such notice on startup. Thanks!